# MongoDB pointers or actual copy?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Sorry for the ambiguousness of the question, I don't really know how to rephrase it. The question is about about MongoDB and the information stored within it.

I have a collection of users:

```
use mydb
db.users.insert({name:"whatever", follow:[])
db.users.insert({name:"whatever2", follow:[])
```

I want a user to follow another:

```
var userToFollow = db.users.findOne({name:"whatever2"});
db.users.update({name:"whatever"}, {$push:{follow:userToFollow}});
/* 
 * I know that in reality, this query will return more than one user, 
 * but as I'm letting mongo create the ids, I don't actually know a better approach.
 * Please enlighten me.
 */
```

That is sort of the way I'm thinking on doing a follow. But I have questions like, is it copying all the user to the follow array or is it actually storing a pointer to that user and it will retrieve it somehow internally when I access it through a query? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's actual copy by your way. Just as what you can retrieve after the operation.
If you want to access the contents quickly from the filed `follow`, it's the way you have done, else you can just store as array of `_id`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a better way to do this (push an Id to an array) than to do 2 queries? And if it is a copy, that means that I can have unupdated data, do you know any way to handle that problem?

Comment: According my understanding on your operations, is it possible to fulfill your target by storing `name` into `follow` directly? That is, `db.user.update({name:"whatever"}, {$addToSet:{follow:"whatever2"}})`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I currently do, I thought there might be a better way. It seems not. Thank you @Wizard .